Keyboard shortcuts no longer work reliably
When I want to vote to close a question, I type mc followed by the numeric codes for the close reason I want. This obviously requires me to have enabled keyboard shortcuts in my profile, which I did as soon as that option became available (something like 10 years ago? Indeed.)
As a regular in SOCVR and related curation efforts, I do this fairly frequently.
However, as of today, two times out of maybe ten it didn't work and I had to use the mouse instead.
I'm used to the keyboard shortcuts being a little erratic, in that if you try to use them before the page has fully loaded, the won't work. But in this instance, I spent a fair amount of time just waiting, and additional time clicking around to make sure my focus wasn't in the wrong place or something. (For example, when you type too fast, sometimes the m gets lost and then the c initiates adding a new comment, at which point subsequent keystrokes only submit literal text into the new comment.)
To respond to VLAZ' comment; just now, I was unable to delete vote a non-answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16961570/874188 (the link will take you to the question if you don't have 10k rep by the time you read this as I will manually click to delete) so for a while there md also wasn't working for me; but mc on that question works even though I didn't reload the page.
I'm guessing this is a regression, in the worst case to deliver this monstrous atrocity.

Is it just MC or have you noticed others misbehaving? Also, if it fails, does it persist (on the same question, maybe until the tab is reloaded)? If it's persistent per question, can you provide a link when next you find one?

@VLAZ Thanks for the question; updated the post with an example. Seems it's completely intermittent.

Just now I tried to use MF to flag as spam and it didn't work, but then the right sidebar updated with some pesky ad and I was able to use the keyboard shortcut after all. Maybe there is something which is really slow to load which I can't see in the problematic cases ...?

Entirely possible a slow ad or some other resource blocking it. On Firefox, you should see a spinner in the tab if it's still waiting to load something (although the page can look ready). I think Chrome has a similar indicator. It's not guaranteed this is the problem but it's a likely culprit.

Oh the good old mc21 on Meta has saved me kilometers on my mouse!

Tentative answer, but VLAZ seems to have identified the culprit in comments. I plonked these into my /etc/hosts and it seems so far to have fixed the problem.
# Block slow Stackoverflow ads
0.0.0.0         cdn.cookielaw.org
0.0.0.0         pagead2.googlesyndication.com

(I think there's a third one which I haven't encountered after I did this.)
It's a good question per se why it takes multiple seconds for the ads to load (at least for me, this seems fairly consistent); and also, whether that really should be blocking keyboard interactions. Ideally, we could have working keyboard shortcuts even when ads are slow.

"Ideally, we could have working keyboard shortcuts even when ads are slow." Yes, please. Is relatively minor but mighty annoying when you have to wait multiple seconds just to interact with a page. Yes, I can use the mouse but if I'm posed to use the keyboard, it's because I want to do something where I don't want to use the mouse. Some tasks are much more comfortable with a keybard. Moreover, repetitive clicking tasks (e.g., "open many questions from the list") do strain my hand. RSI is a thing and repeat clicking is one of the causes.
